# Do not pass on touches on a UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uislider

I have an iPad interface where different views can be moved left-right with one finger (as for e.g. like the Twitter iPad interface).

I have a problem with this, as I have a slider on one view and when I start sliding, the UIGestureRecogniser on the main (underlying) view also start acting on the movement.

Is there a way to prevent this? That only the UISlider takes the touch action, and that the underlying view does not act? I mean to remember there is a variable for this with UIGestureRecognisers, but cannot find it for views/sliders.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the exclusive touch property:

```
[view setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for hours and I following trick work for me.

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *yourScrollView;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
yourScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
}
```